# Incremental model-based Outlier detection

Tags: java, apache-flink, outliers

I am dealing with streaming data (using Java and Apache Flink) and I would like to perform outliers detection. I have a network where each sensor receives a stream. 
Then they send a sampled version of their stream to a "leader" node that combines all the samples and generates a global model.

After that, it sends the global model to each child. The children will use this model in order to detect the outliers. 
This has to happen in a continuous manner (i.e. each time the leader receive x samples it updates the model and broadcast it).

The problem I encountered with the paper/approaches I have found was that in order to build the model I needed to have all the data, and this is not possible. Also is not feasible for the leader to store all the samples it receives.

I am writing down a little example:

Sensor A receives some data and send it to the leader

Sensor B receives some data and send it to the leader

The Leader uses the received values to build a model that is broadcasted.

The two sensors receive other data, for each value they use the received model to perform the outlier Detection.
Then they send the new data to the leader.

The leader updates the model and sends the new updated model to the children.

Which method can I use that allows me to obtain such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Once approach to this would be to have the leader write the model updates to a Kafka topic, and have A and B read those model updates from Kafka (in addition to their sensor streams).

Updated:

One fairly straightforward algorithm for detecting outliers/anomalies that's well suited for streams is t-digest (and yes, it works incrementally). [This page from mapr](https://mapr.com/resources/videos/better-anomaly-detection-t-digest-whiteboardwalkthrough/) will lead you to more information.

Comment: Yes, I have done exactly like this. I am asking if you know any outlier detection model that I can use for this purpose. In particular, it should be possible to update the model incrementally.

Comment: I've updated my answer above to suggest using t-digest.

Comment: Thanks! I have been studying the t-digest but it seems that it is used for calculating a threshold ( http://koff.io/posts/using-t-digest/ ). I don't know how to use this in my data stream in order to find out the anomalies, to my understanding I should use a model and then use the threshold given by the t-digest (as in this project https://github.com/pollo/anomaly_detection/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/anomalydetection/EKGAnomalyDetection.java, but the problem here is that the model is not serializable and does not work incrementally).

Comment: Take a look at Ted Dunning's implementation: https://github.com/tdunning/t-digest/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tdunning/math/stats/TDigest.java I'm pretty sure it is both serializable and amenable to being used incrementally.